# Having trouble deleting node in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having some trouble deleting nodes in Firebase

[image]

This is how I upload my data

```
BigBoy add = new BigBoy(addCate);
          myRef.push().setValue(add);
```

This is how i'm trying to delete my data

```
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("message");
        myRef = database.getReference("message");
String sfasf = Utils.object.getSfasf();
DatabaseReference remove  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("message").child(sfasf);
               remove.removeValue();
```

But the problem is that the node is not being deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't referencing the pushID when I was referencing the specific data node. That was solved by saving the key as well when I upload the data.

Answer (score 0):

Make your firebase call like this -

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("message");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshots : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

           if (dataSnapshots.child("sfasf").exists()) {
                    dataSnapshots.child("sfasf").removeValue();
           } 

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }


});
```

Comment: Still doesn't delete the data

Comment: Checking the issue

Comment: It still doesn't work, it gives me the error Attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object referencer probably because I'm not using Firebase Authentication. Even if I delete that the node is still not getting deleted.

Comment: FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message").child();
myRef.child(sfasf).removeValue()

Comment: Try this once and check

Comment: It still doesn't delete the data, am I forgetting to add something in the Firebase console?

Comment: Wait for sometime,  checking again

Comment: If you want to remove the node from id, then you can use dataSnapshot.removeValue(); inside the if condition

Comment: It says Cannot resolve method removeValue in dataSnapshot.child("sfasf").removeValue();, and it gives a weird error saying that you need a semi colon in the for statement, which I couldn't fix

Comment: Try the updated one. Don't worry, we will make it work

Comment: I am waiting for your response

Comment: We will do it asap, just be in stackoverflow for sometime

Comment: I still get the error cannot resolve removeValue in dataSnapshot.child("sfasf").removeValue();

Comment: Try this inside if condition -

Comment: dataSnapshot.removeValue();

Comment: Get the same error as before, I think remove value isn't a method for datasnapshot anymore

Comment: adding datasnapshot.getRef().removevalue(); allows removevalue to be used but removes all the values from my database

Comment: Because your getRef is the message node

Comment: It's still not working do you have any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

1) You have a reference object but you dont use it. You have created 2 variable references and you dont use them.

2) Your code is wrong in order to remove the node you must specify the key

```
myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.child(key).remove();
```

---edit---

try this

```
myRef.child(key).removeValue();
```

---edit---

From the official documentation:

> The simplest way to delete data is to call removeValue() on a reference to the location of that data. You can also delete by specifying null as the value for another write operation such as setValue() or updateChildren(). You can use this technique with updateChildren() to delete multiple children in a single API call.

Comment: Doesn't delete the data